# Почему случается TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation? Вроде всё правильно сделал

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я решил сделать бота для игры Team Fortress 2. что бы бот показывал сайты с информацией про сервера и давал ссылки на них и когда я запустил своего бота то обнаружил что консоль не любит мой код и отправляет это сообщение:

```
if lowered( 'информацию' ) 
                          ^ 
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

Вот сам код который не хочет работать:

```
@client.command()
async def servers ( ctx ):
    await ctx.send("Тебе нужна информация или играть?")
        if lowered('информация')
            await ctx.send( "Тогда выбирай сервер:" )
            await ctx.send( "401" )
            await ctx.send( "402" )
            await ctx.send( "403" )
            await ctx.send( "404" )
                if lowered("401")
                    await ctx.send( 'Вот информация про Creators.TF | Moscow (West Russia) #401: https://www.gs4u.net/ru/tf2/46.174.48.84:27015.html' )
                elif lowered('402')
                    await ctx.send( 'Вот информация про Creators.TF | Moscow (West Russia) #402: https://www.gs4u.net/ru/tf2/46.174.48.84:27016.html' )
                elif lowered('403')
                    await ctx.send( 'Вот информация про Creators.TF | Moscow (West Russia) #403: https://www.gs4u.net/ru/tf2/46.174.48.84:27017.html' )
                elif lowered('404')
                    await ctx.send( 'Вот информация про Creators.TF | Moscow (West Russia) #404: https://www.gs4u.net/ru/tf2/46.174.48.84:27018.html' )
        elif lowered( 'играть' )
            await ctx.send( "Тогда выбирай сервер:" )
            await ctx.send("401")
            await ctx.send("402")
            await ctx.send("403")
            await ctx.send("404")
                if lowered("401")
                    await ctx.send( 'Подключиться к с.tf #401: steam://connect/46.174.48.84:27015' )
                elif lowered("402")
                    await ctx.send( 'Подключиться к с.tf #402: steam://connect/46.174.48.84:27016' )
                elif lowered("403")
                    await ctx.send( 'Подключиться к с.tf #403: steam://connect/46.174.48.84:27017' )
                elif lowered("403")
                    await ctx.send( 'Подключиться к с.tf #404: steam://connect/46.174.48.84:27018' )
```

Из за своей не опытности я не знаю как решить эту проблему.

Comment: Проверьте, что везде в коде либо пробелы, либо табы

Comment: C 4 строки перед условием лишний отступ. И не только там.

Answer (score 0):

Помог комментарий "C 4 строки перед условием лишний отступ. И не только там." и ответ "Поставить двоеточия после всеми скобками строк имеющих if или elif"
Нужно было убрать один таб(Tab(4 пробела)) перед всеми if и elif и поставить двоеточия после скобочками этих строк

Вот правильный код:

```
@client.command()
async def servers ( ctx ):
    await ctx.send("Тебе нужна информация или играть?")
    if lowered('информация'):
        await ctx.send("Тогда выбирай сервер:")
        await ctx.send("401")
        await ctx.send("402")
        await ctx.send("403")
        await ctx.send("404")
        if lowered("401"):
                await ctx.send('Вот информация про Creators.TF | Moscow (West Russia) #401: https://www.gs4u.net/ru/tf2/46.174.48.84:27015.html')
        elif lowered('402'):
                await ctx.send('Вот информация про Creators.TF | Moscow (West Russia) #402: https://www.gs4u.net/ru/tf2/46.174.48.84:27016.html')
        elif lowered('403'):
                await ctx.send( 'Вот информация про Creators.TF | Moscow (West Russia) #403: https://www.gs4u.net/ru/tf2/46.174.48.84:27017.html')
        elif lowered('404'):
                await ctx.send('Вот информация про Creators.TF | Moscow (West Russia) #404: https://www.gs4u.net/ru/tf2/46.174.48.84:27018.html')
    elif lowered('играть'):
        await ctx.send("Тогда выбирай сервер:")
        await ctx.send("401")
        await ctx.send("402")
        await ctx.send("403")
        await ctx.send("404")
        if lowered("401"):
                await ctx.send('Подключиться к с.tf #401: steam://connect/46.174.48.84:27015')
        elif lowered("402"):
                await ctx.send('Подключиться к с.tf #402: steam://connect/46.174.48.84:27016')
        elif lowered("403"):
                await ctx.send('Подключиться к с.tf #403: steam://connect/46.174.48.84:27017')
        elif lowered("403"):
                await ctx.send('Подключиться к с.tf #404: steam://connect/46.174.48.84:27018')
```